# How to handle duplicates records with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, duplicates, try-catch

My web service get a list of datas to be added on DB.

The table to be write on contains `3 fields`: `(id,userId,contactId)`. On DB `(userId,contactId)` is an `unique key`.

If a duplicate couple of values `(userId,contactId)` is retrieved by web service, I need to handle the exception on java side, and go on adding the remaining records also if a duplicate exception is raised.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/34EbvCbz) the code I'm using.

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
Transaction transaction = null;
try {
    transaction = session.beginTransaction();

    for (int i=0; i<contactsToAdd.size(); ++i)
    {
        Contact contact = new Contact(userId, contactsToAdd.get(i));
        try
        {
            session.saveOrUpdate(contact);                          // line 11
            session.flush();
        }
        catch (HibernateException e)
        {
            transaction.rollback();                                 // line 16
//                  e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            session.clear();                                        // line 21
        }
    }

    transaction.commit();
    return true;
}
catch (HibernateException e) {
    transaction.rollback();                                                 // line 29
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
    session.close();                                                        // line 33
}
```

- When `i` = 0, lines 11, 12, 16, 21 are executed.
- When `i` = 1, lines 11, 12, 16, 21, 29, 30, 33 are executed.

Can you please help me understand why?

Comment: it is better to post the relevant [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) code **inline** with the question and not some external site where the relevant code will disappear from eventually making the question useless to future visitors!

Answer (score 0):

assuming Contact implements Equals and Gethashcode on the two relevant fields

```
Set<Contact> contacts = ...;
for (int i=0; i<contactsToAdd.size(); ++i)
{
    contacts.Add(new Contact(userId, contactsToAdd.get(i)));
}

for (Contact contact in contacts)
{
    Session.Save(contact);
}
```